# Apartment and Garage disappeared in GTA Online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I've just been on GTA 5 online on my character. Both me and my partner have our own characters (on the same profile though) and when I had finished playing, he swapped to his character. He had an apartment with a 10 car garage as well as a separate 10 car garage but this time when he went on to his character they'd vanished and now he only has an apartment with a 6 car garage, no way near where his original apartment was. He rang the mechanic and most of his cars were in storage.

Has this happened to anyone else?
Nothing had changed on my character.
I still have a 10 car garage as well as an apartment with a 10 car garage.

Comment: I have never seen "/ being used as a smilie before. I am impressed.

Comment: @No.7892142 I'm pretty sure the " was supposed to be a : as the periods were all 's.

Answer (score 3):

A similar thing happened to me, but in a worse condition - all my progress was gone; my rank was reset to 1, and i lost my cars, and apartment. I recommend you to contact rockstar support, by posting a question at https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us . They restored my progress within 5 hours I posted the question.... Here's the mail i received- [image]